# How does MySQL implement transactions

Tags: mysql, c, transactions

Can anyone give (or point me to) a high-level overview of how MySQL implements transactions, rollbacks, and retries? I'm staring at some code but before diving in for the weekend I figured it'd be useful if someone could give me a birds-eye view so that I'd know where to start.

EDIT: Maybe I was a little less than clear. I'm not looking for how to use MySQL's client interfaces, I'm looking for how it actually *does* transactions. I'm looking for something like "check int my_isam_start_transaction(..." in my_isam.c.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL only supports transactions in the table type is InnoDB. Otherwise, you have to do all the rollbacks and retries in code. Doing it in code can be really difficult since you may lose the connection to the server, then you can't roll back in a timely manner.

In a nutshell, you "wrap" your set of queries in START TRANSACTION and COMMIT queries.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

InnoDB will automatically rollback in case of failure/disconnect in your code.

Comment: There are other engines that *can* be used so it's more accurate to say transactions are *not* supported on MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the MySQL manual (somewhere on mysql.com), and did a search for "transactions":

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

It's for version 5.0, but it's a pretty repeatable process. For a general-overview, Wikipedia is a good starting point on that whole strange ["ACID"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) concept. However, transactions (and the correct implementation or not, not to mention the various quirks and best practices) depend heavily on the specific DB itself.

Following the magic formula above also yields:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb.html (more detailed information on the InnoDB back-end, which is likely what you'll be using, although their are alternatives that support transactions such as IBMDB2I)

Happy reading.